# Set values in formula fields in crystal report from VB

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm new in vb and crystal report so please help me from my problem. I'm assigning values using vb codes to a formula field from my crystal report. Here is my code:

```
 Dim report As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        report = New report_Student()
        report.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("student").Text = "Slone" & Chr(13) & "Thompson"
        frm_print.viewerReport.ReportSource = report
        frm_print.viewerReport.RefreshReport()
        frm_print.Show()
```

i place this in button click event. Now i have an error on running this, before it loads the crystal report from viewer this error shows:

```
The remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula.
Details: errorKind
Error in formula student:
'Slone
'
```

Comment: I don't have knowledge in Crystal as a part of Vb.net but a guess can you try.. `chrW(13)` instead of `chr(13)`

Comment: Chr(13) is a Carriage return - are you sure that should be in your formula?

Comment: Same error i get @siva
What should i put in my formula? i'm inserting a newline code in formula field. vbnewline or environment.newline don't work also.

Comment: *why* are you inserting a newline in your formula?

Comment: so that in my report it shows like Slone then new line Thompson

Comment: one suggestion is if this is not working then create a local variable and display that something like this `StringVar a:=("student").Text = "Slone" + Chr(13) + "Thompson"`

Comment: well i guess this works now, i assign it to a variable string then insert this on variable "'Slone' & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & 'Thompson'" and pass it to formula field student.

Answer (score 0):

I guess as you have formula field (not text object) you should use formula there:

```
    report.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("student").Text = _
        ControlChars.Quote + "Slone" + ChrW(13) + "Thompson" + ControlChars.Quote
```

So, in result formula will contain one text literal ("Slone\nThompson").

Not tried this, but hope it should work.

If not, then probably you need to use CR inner function ChrW() for newline in next way:

```
    report.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("student").Text = _
        ControlChars.Quote + "Slone" + ControlChars.Quote + _
        " + ChrW(13) + " + _
        ControlChars.Quote + "Thompson" + ControlChars.Quote
```

So, in result two text literals ("Slone" and "Thompson") will be concatenated with result of CR inner function ChrW().

In CR formula editor it will be shown as

```
    "Slone" + ChrW(13) + "Thompson"
```

But I expect 1st way should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a report parameter instead of a formula. In case you need to modify the values inside the report use the parameter inside the formula